# How do you say Cooking from Scratch in French

Tags: traduction, choix-de-mot, alimentation

How do you say "cooking from scratch" in French?

Some suggestions have been *à partir de rien* or *à partir de zero*. 
But they just do not sound right.

Comment: Welcome to French Language. You cannot expect everyone here  to understand more than basic English, and if you want a good answer you should first explain what "cooking from scratch" means. Besides I find the question rather odd, as you probably know France is a country where cooking from scratch is still the most usual way of cooking, even if in this modern day & age a lot of us tend to forget good healthy habits. Can you explain what is cooking from scratch for you an how you relate to home made food.

Comment: Note that "from scratch" generally means not only cooked at home, but without the help even of packages, mixes, etc. For any element you "cheat" on you might say: "I made this Thai curry from scratch, except for the paste, which came ready-made in a jar and I just stirred it in." De A à Z (to add one more option)?

Answer (score 7):

The English "from scratch" means:

> From basic materials or raw ingredients ([wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/from_scratch))

The main point is **the origin** of the product.

When you "cook from scratch" you end with home-made food. [The 2015 decree](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/eli/decret/2015/5/6/EINI1510307D/jo) that was passed in France to redefine the new *fait maison* label for restaurants had to make a point that *fait-maison* implied using fresh & raw products, to end up the controversy that *fait-maison* can include frozen and already half-cooked products. There was a lobby that wanted a special label *à partir de produits bruts*.

Indeed for most French people *fait-maison* does not imply the use of fresh and raw products, if I use frozen pastry to bake a *tarte* I'll still say it's home-made (*fait-maison*) but a restaurant would not be allowed to do that. To add to my point is that, in spite of the decree, a lot of restaurants still feel the need to add *fait maison à partir de produits bruts*.*

Cooking from scratch: *cuisiner **à partir de produits bruts***.

*<sub>[The decree analyzed](https://www.economie.gouv.fr/dispositif-fait-maison-est-simplifie) : La phrase « les plats ‘faits maison’ sont élaborés sur place à partir de produits bruts » ne figurera que sur les cartes des restaurants souhaitant mettre en avant les plats « fait maison »</sub>.

---

*From scratch* est souvent traduit en français par « de zéro » ou « de rien », mais cette traduction ne convient pas dans tous les cas. C'est valable quand au départ il n'y a rien (zéro c'est rien, le néant). La traduction par « de zéro » convient par exemple pour rendre *he built his fortune from scratch* mais pas dans des expressions où on construit quelque chose à partir de matériaux existants, comme *build one's house from scratch* (bâtir sa maison **de toutes pièces**, ou **de A à Z**) ou *cooking from scratch*.

Comment: You're not wrong but it does sound overly technical. I don't think anybody would use it in everyday conversation.

Comment: @0xFEE1DEAD On emploie souvent aussi « à partir de produits frais », beaucoup de restaurants affichent ça aussi, mais c'est moins large que « bruts ».

Comment: En effet, je prefere « à partir de produits frais ». Apres ca depend de l'utilisation. Ce qui a du sens dans le contexte de la restauration n'est pas forcement naturel dans un contexte familier. Dire "je l'ai fait moi-meme, a partir de produits frais" ne me choque pas.

Comment: @Laure Juste pour vérifier : c'est-à-dire que le décret n'est pas vraiment en phase avec ce que disent la majorité des français, mais si M. Tout-le-monde entendait par « fait-maison » ce que la loi y entend, l'expression serait plus ou moins adéquate ?

Comment: @LukeSawczak La question de définir ce que veut dire *fait maison* est ce qu'on appelle dans le réseau stackexchange "primarily opinion"based". Pour moi, comme pour certains lobbyistes de la restauration, « fait maison » n'implique pas l'utilisation de produits bruts.  Pour calmer les passions le décret est un compromis pour calmer les passions et donc les législateurs ont défini à leur manière le sens de fait maison spécifiquement pour ce décret, c'est pour ça que des restaurateurs continuent à préciser « Fait maison à partir de produits bruts ».

Comment: Suite : De toute façon en anglais aussi *home-made* et *cooked from scratch*  sont des concepts différentes, comme tu le dis dans ton commentaire sous la question.  Fais une recherche sur *home-made* et *cooking from scratch* pour voir le débat dans le monde anglophone. C'est pour ça que je demandais à l'OP de définir ce qu'il entendait par ce terme. Mais il n'a pas pris la peine de répondre... je soupçonne que ce n'est pas un anglophone (vu les erreurs que tu as corrigées) et que peut-être il ne savait pas très bien ce que ça veut dire en anglais.

Comment: Merci, @Laure, c'est intéressant les décrets linguistiques faits exprès pour « calmer les passions » attisées par la cuisine ! Mais c'est vrai, au bout du compte on ne sait pas vraiment le sens que souhaite l'OP.

Answer (score 5):

In Québec, we also use this expression:

> Fait de mes (ses, tes) propres mains

But I think that the answer @0xFEE1DEAD gave is the best:

> Fait maison

Comment: Note that there's also "fait main" (handmade) as in "Fabriqué manuellement ou artisanalement ; qui n'est pas issu de l'industrie."

Answer (score 3):

Consider *fait maison* (homemade)

> Fait par ses propres soins, à la maison, réalisé par soi-même.
>
> Exemple : Il goûta les deux tartes, apparemment identiques, et à l'industrielle il préféra celle faite maison, par les soins de sa femme, pourtant novice dans le domaine culinaire.

Source: http://www.linternaute.com/dictionnaire/fr/definition/fait-maison/

Comment: But "homemade" does not imply from scratch....  what do you propose for "from scratch" ?

Answer (score 3):

It's a little wordy but I would say:

- *Cuisiner à partir d'[**aliments non-transformés**](http://routinesante.com/les-aliments-transformes-vs-les-aliments-non-transformes/)*.